# open() : Device or resource busy (/dev/rtc(x))

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

So I have an RTC hooked up on my beaglebone and it works fine through cat'ing the `/sys/class/rtc/rtx(x)/time file`, however my `C` code to monitor the time has an error I can't seem to solve.

```
if ((rtc_fd = open(RTC, O_RDONLY, 444)) < 0)
    REPORT_ERROR("open(RTC)");
```

where RTC is the path to `/dev/rtc1`. `REPORT_ERROR` is a macro function for reporting custom errors.

Anyways, I am running this code just before a `for` loop with 10 iterations and it is outputting to a log file. I always get the `strerror(perror)` message:
*Device or resource busy* 
But then it still goes on to give me my 10 outputs that are correct.

I am using `close()` at the end as well.

What gives?

edit: Perhaps I should add that this is running in a daemonized process, and I am using `iocotl()` with `RTC_RD_TIME` during the loop.

```
#define REPORT_ERROR(X) do {\
        fprintf(log,"err@ "X": %s@ %s:%d\n",\
        strerror(errno), __FILE__, __LINE__ - 1);\
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
        } while(0)

#define RTC "/dev/rtc1"

int main(void)
{
    int rtc_fd;
    FILE *log;
    struct rtc_time tm;

    if ((log = fopen(LOG_FILE, "a+")) == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if ((dup2(fileno(log), STDERR_FILENO)) < 0)
        REPORT_ERROR("dup2()");

    if ((rtc_fd = open(RTC, O_RDONLY, 444)) < 0)
        REPORT_ERROR("open(RTC)");

    /* Main loop */
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if ((ioctl(rtc_fd, RTC_RD_TIME, &rtctime)) != 0)
            REPORT_ERROR("ioctl(rtc_fd)");

        fprintf(log, "%02d:%02d:%02.lf   %d-%d-%d\n", tm.hour, tm.minute,
                tm.second, tm.mon + 1, tm.mday, tm.year + 1900);
        sleep(1);
    }

    close(rtc_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
err@ open(RTC): Device or resource busy@ ha-daemon.c:80
05:06:09   2-12-2015
05:06:10   2-12-2015
05:06:11   2-12-2015
05:06:12   2-12-2015
05:06:13   2-12-2015
05:06:14   2-12-2015
05:06:15   2-12-2015
05:06:16   2-12-2015
05:06:17   2-12-2015
05:06:18   2-12-2015
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Have you tried opening your device globally?

Comment: As for your actual problem (opening the device) are you *sure* that no other process have the exact same device opened already?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, the FILE *log is not undefined, I just didnt snip that code in, it is now. I thought somebody might know the cause of this problem without seeing so much of the code, after all I did say in my question that the output is correct after the initial error message..

Comment: @Shehryar I am not sure what you mean by opening the device globally? If I su than cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc1/time I can get the time.

Comment: To clarify, *which* function call gives you the error? The `open` call? The `ioctl` call? And are you sure the macro is actually used to print the message? Because if the message is printed by the macro then the process should *exit* immediately. Also please provide *actual* output.

Comment: As for debugging the problem, does it work if you *don't* run it as a daemon? Otherwise you might want to run in a debugger to check what's happening. You can also add way more logging output, to trace the code in more details if you can't run in a debugger.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I'm sure it's the macro printing the message, but that is a good point about how it should be exiting immediately. I am going to try it without running as a daemon and I'll post updates, first I gotta eat though. I edited the question with the output. Line 80 is where the open() call is. edit: I forgot to ask, how can I check if another process is accessing /dev/rtc1? I run ps aux | grep rtc  and see a process /sbin/init fixrtc

Comment: I modified to code minimally so that it compiles for me (gcc / Ubuntu 14.04 64-bits). It's awaiting peer review. Here it works as expected: either it runs with no error message, or it prints an error message and exits immediately.

Comment: Regarding a way to check which process has files open, you can use [`lsof`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) to list open files, then `grep` for e.g. `rtc1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but my edit to the question got rejected with the comment that I should post it as an answer instead. So here it goes.

The code, as posted, does not compile. I modified it minimally so that it compiles with no warnings and I can test it. Here is the list of changes. Some of them may be specific to my environment (gcc 4.8.1 / Ubuntu Linux 14.04 / x86-64):

- added all the missing `#include`s
- defined `LOG_FILE`, defining it as `/dev/tty` just makes testing easier
- replaced `/dev/rtc1` by `/dev/rtc0` (I have no rtc1)
- replaced `&rtctime` (the last argument of the ioctl) by `&tm`, otherwise it would neither make sense nor compile
- fixed the printf format: "%02d" instead of "%02.lf"
- put the correct names for the rtctime struct fields: `tm_hour`, `tm_min`, etc.

And here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/rtc.h>

#define LOG_FILE "/dev/tty"

#define REPORT_ERROR(X) do {\
        fprintf(log,"err@ "X": %s@ %s:%d\n",\
        strerror(errno), __FILE__, __LINE__ - 1);\
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
        } while(0)

#define RTC "/dev/rtc0"

int main(void)
{
    int rtc_fd;
    FILE *log;
    struct rtc_time tm;

    if ((log = fopen(LOG_FILE, "a+")) == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if ((dup2(fileno(log), STDERR_FILENO)) < 0)
        REPORT_ERROR("dup2()");

    if ((rtc_fd = open(RTC, O_RDONLY, 444)) < 0)
        REPORT_ERROR("open(RTC)");

    /* Main loop */
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if ((ioctl(rtc_fd, RTC_RD_TIME, &tm)) != 0)
            REPORT_ERROR("ioctl(rtc_fd)");

        fprintf(log, "%02d:%02d:%02d   %d-%d-%d\n", tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min,
                tm.tm_sec, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_year + 1900);
        sleep(1);
    }

    close(rtc_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

The test results: It compiles and works as expected. Either it runs with no error message, or it prints an error message and exits immediately. If one instance of the program is running, starting a second instance gives the "Device or resource busy" error message, as expected.

In other words, "works for me".